# Is every element in a power set a sub set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have understood so far that an element cannot be a sub set of itself. If A = {1,2,{3}} and {3} is not a sub set of A. But in my textbook it has been given that every element in a power set is a subset. So isn't there a contradiction?

Comment: Every element of the power-set of a set $A$ is a *subset* of the set $A$. This is so simply because the power set is **defined** as the set of **all** subsets.

Comment: Okay that makes sense

Comment: And YES : $\{ 3 \}$ is not a subset of $A$. It is an element of $A$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that although $\{3\}$ is not a subset of $A$, $\{\{3\}\}$ *is*.  Note the subtle difference between the two.  $\{3\}$ is a set with one element, that element being the number $3$.  On the other hand $\{\{3\}\}$ is also a set with one element, but in this case that element is the *set which contains $3$*.

Comment: It's also just not true, either, that an element $x\in A$ can't also be a subset of $A$. Consider the usual implementation of the natural number 2, $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}$; both members of this set are also subsets of this set.

Comment: (In this case, I do not mean my $A$ in the above comment to refer to the one in your post; it's my default letter for an arbitrary set, which I realize might cause confusion in this instance.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element of a power set is a subset of *the set you formed the powerset for*, not of the powerset *itself*. $pow(A) := \{X: X \subseteq A\}$, so by definition, every element of $pow(A)$ is a subset of $A$, but no element of $pow(A)$ is a subset of $pow(A)$, and no element of $A$ is a subset of $A$.
As you correctly noted, $\{3\}$ - a set with one element, namely the element $3$ - is not a subset, but an element of $\{A\}$. But $\{\{3\}\}$ - a set with one element, namely the element $\{3\}$ - is an *element of the powerset* of $A$ and therefore a *subset of $A$*.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should **avoid speaking of " an element" or of " a subset" in an absolute sense**, as if there were categories of things, some being once and for all and by nature elements, or once and for all and by nature subsets.

In fact the terms " element" and "subset" are **relational** : element **OF** a given set, subset **OF** a given set. One cannot be simply " a brother" , one has to be a brother OF someone...same thing for sets.

For example, take take the object {4}. This object is a set. **Relatively to** the set

{{4}, { 5,6} }

our object {4} is an **element**. So we can say that :

the set {4} belongs to the set  {{4}, { 5,6} }. Notice that the set {{4}, { 5,6} } has 2 elements, and each of these two elements is a set.

Now, **relatively to the set { 4,5,6}** ( which has 3 elements), our object {4} is **not an element**. There is absolutely no contradiction here, if you keep in mind that "element" is a relative term: "being an element OF a given set" does not contradict "not being an element of another set" ( in the same manner as " Peter is a brother of John" does not contradict " Peter is not a brother of Alice").

**So what is the object {4} relatively to the set { 4,5,6}?  The proper relation here is the inclusion relation** : {4} is included in the set { 4,5,6}, it is a subset of { 4,5,6} ( some say also " a part of" { 4,5,6} ).

How to explain that {4} is included in the set { 4,5,6}? Remember that " **a set X is included in a set Y just in case all the elements of X are also elements of Y"**. Now, can you see an element of the one-element set {4} that is not also an element of the three-elements set { 4,5,6}? If you answer "no", you know that the set {4} "passes the test" of inclusion , and is therefore included in { 4,5,6}.

**Since the set {4} is a subset of { 4,5,6} ( is included in that set), the set {4} is an element of the power set of the set { 4,5,6}**. That comes from the definition of a power set. By definition, the power set of { 4,5,6} is the collection of the subsets of the set { 4,5,6}.

Being given that {4} is a subset of { 4,5,6}, it follows that the set {4}is an element of the power set of { 4,5,6}. And that is logical : every subset of a set S is an element of the collection of the subsets of S, and the power set of S is just this collection.

Remark. DEFINITION : the power set of a set S is the set that **has as elements** all the **subsets** **of S.**

Now let us consider some general " laws" regarding these relations ( element of, subset of)

(1) **No set is an element of itself.** ( But nothing prevents a set from being an element of another set).

(2) **Every set is a subset of itself**, every set is included in itself.  ( Take any set, say {a, b,c}. Can you see an element of the set {a, b,c} that is not an element of the set {a, b,c}? Of course not! So the set {a, b,c} passes the test of inclusion, relatively to itself: the set {a, b,c} is a subset of the set {a, b,c}, that is to say, of itself. I said **subset**, not member!)

(3) **Every set is an element of its power set** .

Explanation :

(a) If a set X is a subset of a set Y, then X is an element of the power set of Y.

(b) But, the set Y is itself a subset of Y ( itself), because of law (2) above.

(c) Therefore, the set Y is an element of its own power set.

Answer (score 1):

A set $B$ is a subset of $A \iff (x \in B \Rightarrow  x \in A).$ For your example take $B = \{ 3\} $ then $B$ is a subset of $A$ if and only if $3 \in A$, but this is not the case since $A$ only contains $1,2,\{ 3\}$ all of which are not $3$. Therefore $B$ is not a subset of $A$.

The power set of a set $A$ is by definition the collection of all subsets of $A$ so any subset of $A$ is by definition in $A$'s power set.